Is $\dfrac{\text{concatenation of first n perfect nth powers}}{1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+n^{n}}$ ever an integer?
Is $\dfrac{\text{concatenation of first n perfect nth powers}}{1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+n^{n}}$ ever an integer?
Note: concatenation of first $n$ perfect $n^{th}$ powers are numbers like $14$ (when $n=2$), $1827$ (when $n=3$), $11681256$ (when $n=4$).
I know that if $n\equiv2,5,9,10,12,14,15,19\pmod{20}$, then the last digit of $1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+n^{n}$ is $5$.
If $n\equiv2,9,12,14,19\pmod{20}$, then the last digit of numerator is not $5$, while the last digit of denominator is $5$, so the equation is not an integer.When $n\equiv15\pmod{20}$, then the numerator is odd, while the denominator is even, so the expression is not an integer.
For $n\equiv3,11\pmod{20}$, the numerator is odd, while the denominator is even, therefore the expression is not an integer.
So the only possibilities such that $\dfrac{\text{concatenation of first n perfect nth powers}}{1^{n}+2^{n}+3^{n}+\cdots+n^{n}}$ is an integer is when $n\equiv0,1,4,5,6,7,8,10,13,16,17,18\pmod{20}$.
By using Pari GP, I did check all values of $n$ up to $6000$, and there was no such $n$.

You can also eliminate $n =4k+1$.
